# Does PES/FIFA support online multiplayer for older versions?

Tags: fifa-17

Say I want to play PES 2017 / FIFA 2017 online today, does the company maintain support it?

Or has the online feature for 2017 been shut down since the 2018 version got released?

Answer (score 1):

According to  [EA's](https://help.ea.com/en/fifa/fifa-17/) own site, the Fifa 17 servers for PS3, PS4, X360 are still up and running while the Xbox one and Origin servers for it are down.

For PES, it is so, that for every game the lifespan of the servers are only a few years, 2-3 normally. That means, according to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/WEPES/comments/7g1n96/noob_here_pes_2017_termination_of_online_services/) that the server for PES 17 was shut down in 2018.[image]